# MAX function sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table userlog (ID, Login (datetime), UserID, IP, UserAgengt...)

What I want is to get all data for eachuser for newest Login.

```
Select UserID, MAX(Login), IP, UserAgent
From userlog
Group by UserID, IP, UserAgent
```

This will give me multiple records for one user if he have multiple IPs and/or UserAgent... and I want data for row which have max login date.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way to do this is using the window function `row_number()`:

```
select ul.UserID, ul.Login, ul.IP, ul.UserAgent
from (Select ul.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by login desc) as seqnum
      From userlog ul
     ) ul
where seqnum = 1
```

You don't have to use `group by` for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select u1.UserID, u1.Login, u1.IP, u1.UserAgent
From userlog u1
inner join 
(
   Select UserID, max(Login) as mLogin
   From userlog
   Group by UserID
) u2 on u1.UserID = u2.UserID and u2.mLogin = u1.Login
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a solution different from joining table itself, but obviously there isn't one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT max.userid, max.maxlog, ul.ip, ul.useragent
FROM
(Select UserID, Max(Login) maxlog
From userlog
group by userID)
max
inner join userlog ul on ul.userid=max.userid and ul.login=max.maxlog
```